# SQLiteOpenHelper for sms database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, simplecursoradapter, sqliteopenhelper

I am working on sms app and I had a question is SQLiteOpenHelper necessary to manage sms database.
How do I create class to map all sms database. I read tutorial on how to create SQLiteOpenHelper for 
[contacts manager](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) and I want to create same type of class for sms database. 
Would be really helpful if anybody has sample code for this. 
I want to have methods to get sms by ID, get sms by thread, get address, get body, get date, delete sms etc.
Currently I am doing this in simplecursoradapter.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow nowadays (see item #5 on http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I just want some help in creating SQLiteOpenHelper for sms database